# How to add DISTINCT, GROUP BY clause in drupal view

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-views, aggregate-functions

I'm using drupal 6 and i've created a view and in view query i want to add

GROUP BY AND DISTINCT CLAUSE.

For that i tried to use **views_groupby** contributed module but it only provide **COUNT** SQL Aggregation Function.

I don't know how to add group by clause and distinct clause in view query using  `hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)`.

So that it look like this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(node.nid) AS nid, OTHER_COLUMN 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE ON JOIN_CONDITION 
GROUP BY nid
```

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your View edit form, under **Basic Settings**, try turning the **Distinct** setting on.

You may also try to use the **Gear Icon** for the **Style** section under **Basic Settings**. There you can specify a field to group by, if your row style is fields.

Comment: using style section under basic settings only split the table row that separate each row by the field you put in grouping field dropdown. But it does not alter the query as i mentioned in my question. By the way i need to check DISTINCT setting as you suggested. Its looking good for now. I'm going to check it. Thanks.

Comment: By default it's applying group by clause on nid. Do you know how to apply group by clause other than nid.

Comment: The only way that I am aware of to apply the Group By clause on something other than the NID, is to use 'basic settings -> style -> settings: group by field'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you are suggesting, is not gonna work in my requirement. As i mentioned in my very first comment. But your answer helped me a lot. So i'm accepting it with big smile.

Comment: Thank you. Alternatively, you should check out hook_views_query_alter (http://views.doc.logrus.com/). With that you should be able to have a custom module intercept and rewrite the query to your liking.

Comment: So, this is not the solution to the problem in the question, then? Confused.

Answer (score 3):

**Group By** is not working on hook_views_query_alter and it is known as drupal views module issue. which is reported at https://drupal.org/node/590534, http://drupal.org/node/1608742, http://drupal.org/node/389230#comment-2637200

Also views Aggregation Functions is not given desired result, because it will add all fields and sort order fields to group by criteria.
So, You should use other hooks such as **hook_query_alter**.

```
function hook_query_alter( &$query) {

  if($query->alterMetaData['view']->name == "your_views_name"){
     $query->groupBy("domain_source.domain_id");
     //also you can unset other group by critera by using, unset($query->getGroupBy());
  }
}
```

Comment: @B Ravanbakhsh, This hook is available only in drupal 7 and above version.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, you will add "Group by" that way:

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\AlterableInterface;

function MYMODULE_query_alter(AlterableInterface $query) {
  if (isset($query->alterMetaData['view'])) {
    if($query->alterMetaData['view']->id() == 'replace_by_view_machine_name') {
      // Group by UID to remove duplicates from View results
      $query->groupBy('users_field_data.uid');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') {
    $query->add_field('table', 'field', 'alias', array('function', groupby));
    $query->add_groupby('table.field');
  }
}
```